# What's the difference between event's Unique-ID and Channel-Call-UUID?

Tags: freeswitch

Freeswitch events contain two variables (`Unique-ID` and `Channel-Call-UUID`) that seem to always be set to the exact same value: the leg's unique identifier.

I don't see the purpose of this and while [`Unique-ID` has a one-line documentation on FS's wiki](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Channel_Variables) ("uuid of this channel's call leg"), `Channel-Call-UUID` doesn't.
Even worse: I came accross [two examples](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_List) where their values were different:

```
[...]
Channel-Call-UUID:  c9bbde8b-379b-45d4-b193-3f761a44f3e2
Unique-ID:  81273088-c31f-4469-85a6-c878e42210e5
[...]

[...]
Channel-Call-UUID: ada7f3de-2374-4144-9b1d-eade29df0779
Unique-ID: f3ebca6c-d9cd-4f89-ae12-748e6c479dda
[...]
```

I need to be able to clearly identify a leg in my code, so I'd like to know

- which one is the most accurate and
- what's the purpose of the other one

Comment: +1 This was so useful! Just found a mistake in my code where I was using the wrong one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- "`Unique-ID`" identifies the leg of the current channel (this value seems to always be identical to "`Caller-Unique-ID`", [documented as](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Channel_Variables#Info_Application_Variable_Names_.28variable_xxxx.29) "This channel's uuid").
- "`Channel-Call-UUID`" is an ID that can be used to identify answered/bridged channels. It seems to be derived from the "`Unique-ID`" of the channel's creator.
  The value of "`Channel-Call-UUID`" of the b-leg (the callee) differs from its "`Unique-ID`", but it is identical to the value of the "`Other-Leg-Unique-ID`" header.

The source code (`src/switch_channel.c`) supports my previous claims:

```
if ((v = switch_channel_get_variable(channel, "call_uuid"))) {
        switch_event_add_header_string(event, SWITCH_STACK_BOTTOM, "Channel-Call-UUID", v);
} else {
        switch_event_add_header_string(event, SWITCH_STACK_BOTTOM, "Channel-Call-UUID", switch_core_session_get_uuid(channel->session));
}
```